# Delete the Repeating Strings from an array/arraylist

Tags: java, indexing, hashmap

Below is a code in which I am trying to get the contents of files from a folder (Tester) which has some text files. After that I have to make a dictionary out of all the words present in the text files. I am getting the words (Strings) but they are repeating and I have to delete the repeating words.

Example:

file1 - `John is coding` and file2 - `John is really not coding`.

So the output I want is - `John is coding really not`, i.e. not repeating ones.

Moreover I have to make a matrix of all the words and the corresponding text files in which it is present (just like an indexer).
Example:

```
             file1         file2


     John      1              1

       is      1              1

   coding      1              1

   really      0              1

     not       0              1
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I am stuck.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File folder = new File("/home/gaurav/Tester");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];

        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            String[] a = content.split(" ");

            for (String s : a) {
                if (!array.contains(a)) {
                    array.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(array.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Once you have the array with duplicates you can do:

```
array = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(array));
```

Set will remove the duplicates and since it is liked it will perserve the order

In this piece of code you were trying not to add duplicates:

```
        for(String s:a){

            if(!array.contains(a))
             array.add(s);
        }
```

your mistakes is that you are checking contains(a) instead of contains(s)
Also a good idea would be to trim s before comparing or adding it. So do:

```
       for(String s:a){
          s = s.trim()
          if(!array.contains(s))
          array.add(s);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set`, since it contains no duplicate elements:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
// ...
for(String word: a) {
    words.add(word);
}
```